# A question about the syntax

Tags: syntax, algorithm

I have $3$ elementary questions to ask and I thank you in advance.

Question N°1.

What is the right syntax for $$y\equiv0\pmod {2}$$ in the code below?

```
 Solve[x == 3 y + \[Epsilon] && Mod[y,2], {x, y}, Integers]
```

Question N°2.

Mathematica ask to specify $\epsilon$. How should I? What is the right syntax for? Does the following is correct?

```
Solve[x == 3 y + e && Mod[y, 2] == 0, {e,0,1}, {x, y}, Integers]
```

Question N°3.

At last, my previous computational query committed 8 GB how can I remove the kernel cache?

Comment: Try expressing your condition as `Mod[y, 2] == 0`.

Comment: @MarcoB. Thank You. I will

Comment: Q2 seems solved by MarcoB's suggestion.  Q3 seems completely different.  Ideally questions should be focused on single problem or issue.  (You might have noticed that someone has voted to put the question on hold as too broad.)

Answer (score 1):

Questions 1 and 2:

```
Solve[x == 3 y + e && Mod[y, 2] == 0 && 0 <= e <= 1, {x, y}, Integers]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 
>     ConditionalExpression[1 + 2 (3 C[1] - 3 C[2]), (C[1] | C[2]) ∈ Integers && 
>       C[1] >= 0 && C[2] >= 0 && e == 1], 
>   y -> 
>     ConditionalExpression[2 (C[1] - C[2]), (C[1] | C[2]) ∈ Integers && 
>       C[1] >= 0 && C[2] >= 0 && e == 1]}, 
>  {x -> 
>     ConditionalExpression[2 (3 C[1] - 3 C[2]), (C[1] | C[2]) ∈ Integers && 
>       C[1] >= 0 && C[2] >= 0 && e == 0], 
>   y -> ConditionalExpression[2 (C[1] - C[2]), (C[1] | C[2]) ∈ Integers && 
>       C[1] >= 0 && C[2] >= 0 && e == 0]}}
> ```

Question 3:

This question is not clear. I don't understand what you mean by "kernel cache". However, you might try the following:

1. Save your work.
2. Click on Quit Kernel > Local in the Evaluation menu
3. Click on Start Kernel > Local in the Evaluation menu
4. Evaluate `$HistoryLength = 0` (optional -- this slows memory use in new kernel)

That should free up a lot of memory, but of course the new kernel won't know anything about what was evaluated before it was started.